# Why can't this copy be automatically replaced with a move?

Tags: c++11, move-semantics

Classes for testing:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct inner
{
        std::string value;

        inner() : value("test") {
                std::cerr << "inner default construct\n";
        }
        inner(inner &&mv) : value(std::move(mv.value)) {
                std::cerr << "inner move construct\n";
        }
        inner(inner const &copy) : value(copy.value) {
                std::cerr << "inner copy construct\n";
        }
};

struct outer
{
        inner value;
        outer() {}
        outer(inner v)
                : value(v)
        {}
};
```

A simple test of move semantics does what I expected:

```
inner mover(inner x)
{
        return x;
}
int main()
{
        inner i;
        auto q = mover(std::move(i));
        return 0;
}
```

... which outputs:

> inner default construct
>
> inner move construct
>
> inner move construct

But this main does something I did not expect:

```
int main()
{
        inner i;
        outer o(std::move(i));
        return 0;
}
```

> inner default construct
>
> inner move construct
>
> inner copy construct

I was expecting the copy to instead be another move, as it is in the first main.  Why is the optimization to use move available in the first case but not in the second?

I realize that I could explicitly call std::move in the `outer(inner v)` constructor.... but why is that required?  Why can't the compiler do an implicit move?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am no expert in C++11 rvalue sematics, but `outer` does not have a constructor that accepts an `inner` rvalue reference, so the compiler has no choice but to make an `inner` copy since the input parameter of the `outer` constructor is an lvalue and thus has to invoke the `inner` copy constructor and not the move constructor when initializing the `outer::v` member.

The reason you don't get the copy in the `mover()` example is likely due to [Return Value Optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization), eliminating the need for any copy if the input `inner` instance can be moved directly to the target `q` variable, thus invoking the `inner` move constructor instead of the copy constructor.

Comment: You can move into an argument taken by value

Comment: Right, which would account for the `inner move construct` message when the input `inner` instance is created before being passed to the `outer` constructor.  But inside of that constructor, the `inner v` parameter is an lvalue, not an rvalue. Since an lvalue cannot be bound to an rvalue reference, the `outer::v` member cannot be initialized via the `inner` move constructor, only the copy constructor, thus the `inner copy construct` message.

Answer (score 3):

You need to say `: value(std::move(v))` in the initializer list.

Comment: I know that will work, my question is why is that required?  I'll edit the question to be more clear.

Comment: @SoapBox: I don't understand that question - without the `move`, `v` is an lvalue and you cannot get the move constructor.

Comment: Isn't "x" an l-value in the case of returning from a function (in my first example)?  Why can that one be moved but the one in the constructor cannot?

Comment: [Return Value Optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization)

Comment: @SoapBox: `x` is not an xvalue. In any event, the "move-on-return" rule doesn't say anything about xvalues. It's a separate rule.